# displaying branched XML on a tree component in flex

Tags: apache-flex

please i have a namespaced  Xml structure :

```
<rootlevel xmlns="http://www.wigo.org/simo"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wigo.org/wigo ./schemas/lexicon.xsd">
<name>simulation</name>
<num_vars>
    <variable>
        <name>BMASS_COLLECT_PROP_NAT_REM</name>
              </variable>
    </num_vars>
```

now, i have a labelFunction
that passes in the xml..as an object but when i ran the programme, the tree view has each node, name, num_vars and variable as branches but the content in each of them was null and blank.

So, my question is how can i properly display the  namespaced XML on a tree view such that it shows every branches and elements in each branch?

```
private function treeLabel(item:Object):String{
var label:String = item.localName();
return label;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with a `Label`? Is there a reason you can't use a `Tree` control instead?

Comment: hi, that is because the dataProvider of the tree using the labelFunction is dynamically loaded.

Comment: besides, is there really a way to return XMLs using labelFunction? i tried to modify the signature by returning an XML instead of a String but that wasn't cool.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to parse `XML` into a strong-typed object [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607617/hiding-nodes-in-a-flex-tree-component-keeping-the-children-visible/5611102#5611102).