# eliminating the folder icon of a tree view component

Tags: apache-flex, tree

does anyone knows how i could just eliminate the folder icon of a tree control and display only the leaf?

supposing i have an xml structure looking this :

```
<xml>
 <name>
   john
 </name>
</xml>
```

anyone knows how i could just display the john and hide the name?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607617/680503) which is almost the same. And you can use data descriptors to make tree nodes/leaves displaying according with your restrictions. See [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_6.html) for details.